# android studio will not inflate my xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, methods, layout-inflater

i have a problem in android studio where it will not inflate my xml to my java file when the emulator is loaded and it also gives me a problem in one of my methods saying the support v4 is required though it has already been imported.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
// Tab Titles
private String tabtitles[] = new String[] {"Home","Shouters"};
Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}


    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        // Open Fragment home.java
        case 0:
            FragmentHome fragmenthome = new FragmentHome();
            return fragmenthome;

        // Open Fragment shouters.java
        case 1:
            FragmentShouters fragmentshouter = new FragmentShouters();
            return fragmentshouter;


    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}
}
```

the v4 problem is where i getitem for fragment home

```
public class FragmentHome extends Activity {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment home.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, container, false);
    return view;
```

this problem is where my inflation wont occur for me ?

Comment: post your xml and logcat

Comment: can you share the xml file? and the logcat error also

Comment: FragmentHome must extend Fragment not Activity !

Comment: You need to use setContentView bcz it is extended to activity and if you want to continue same code then just extend it to Fragment.

Comment: @Mahfa was correct that was my problem

Comment: glad i could help u :) @AlexanderRufus

Comment: Posted a new question if you could maybe add your input or thoughts on it ? @mahfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FragmentHome should extend Fragment, not Activity